# Can't reassign function expression name

Tags: javascript

```js
!function b() {
  b = 20;
  console.log(b);
}()
```

Expected output: 20, but the result output is a function, what happened?

Comment: You called your global variable and the function the same name: `b`. Change one of them.

Comment: Remove the name of the function and it should work.

Comment: Please do not hop on a downvote train without thinking. This is a fine question regarding some odd behavior from the interpreter. *Why* does `b = 20;` not error yet also not reassign the reference to `b` yet also not assign a property of `window`? There is a good answer waiting to be written here.

Comment: @FelipeZavan Actually it's local, but still collides...

Answer (score 2):

In strict mode, the assignment throws a `TypeError`, saying "Assignment to constant variable." The problem here is that named function expressions cannot have their names reassigned in the function body.

This behavior is specified in the ECMAScript 5 description of [`CreateImmutableBinding`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1.1.7) and [`Function Definition`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13).

> The production
>   `FunctionExpression : function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }`
>   is evaluated as follows:
>   Call the **CreateImmutableBinding** concrete method of envRec passing the String value of `Identifier` as the argument.

```js
!function b(){
    "use strict";
    b=20;
    console.log(b);
}();
```

Using `var b = 20` can fix the error, as it creates a variable scoped to the function body, rather than trying to reassign the function expression's name.

```js
!function b(){
    "use strict";
    var b = 20;
    console.log(b);
}();
```

Comment: Interesting...Why is the function constant in this context, yet when it's invoked by name instead of by IIFE reassigning works just fine?

Comment: Fantastic, I poked through the spec but it is so dense. Nice answer.

Comment: @Klaycon Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please change either function name or your global variable, both cannot have same name

Comment: They clearly can, as there is no error. It is just producing questionable behavior, which is the source of the asker's question. To clarify, it doesn't seem to be a global variable, as referencing `b` outside the function throws an error.